# Show that ${n\choose k}$ is divisible by a prime greater than $k > 0$ when $n \ge 2k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

> Show that ${n\choose k}$ is divisible by a prime greater than $k > 0$ when $n \ge 2k$.

I know ${n\choose k} = \dfrac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!},$ but I can't seem to justify why the only primes among $n,n-1,\cdots, n-k+1$ can't all be at most $k$. Obviously there's a multiple of $k$ among $n,n-1,\cdots, n-k+1$. It might be useful to use some modular arithmetic properties or theorems (e.g. Wilson's theorem) or maybe even the Pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Maybe Bertrand's postulate with some care because $n-k\geq k$.

Comment: Erdös' proof is given here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the **Sylvester–Schur theorem**, proven by Sylvester, “[On arithmetical series](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN599484047_0021?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B5%5D%7D)” (1892); Schur, “Einige Sätze über Primzahlen mit Anwendungen auf Irreduzibilitätsfragen” (1929); and more elementarily by Erdős, “[A theorem of Sylvester and Schur](https://users.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1934-01.pdf)” (1934).

Answer (score 2):

By *Bertrand's postulate*,  which was verified by Chebyshev in 1852, there's always at least one prime $p$ between $k$ and $2k$:  $$k\lt p\lt2k$$.

It's now known as *Chebyshev's theorem*.

The result follows easily for $n=2k$.

---

For $n\gt2k$, we need something more. Because if $n=2k+l$, we now need a prime $p$ such that $$k+l\lt p\le2k+l$$.

Comment: Is there a method that doesn't use Bertrand's postule? It's fine if you can't think of one, but I was just curious.

Comment: I haven't found one yet.

Comment: How do you know there's a prime p such that $k+l < p < 2k+l$? Consider $n = 5, k = 2, l = 1.$

Comment: Right,  that's my point.   That's the part that's unresolved.  I should have less than or equal there btw.

Comment: I'm just gonna add the following link for reference (also the PNT says $\pi(n)/(n/\log n)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221166/smallest-epsilon-0-for-which-theres-always-a-prime-between-n-and-1-ep#:~:text=for%20any%20%CF%B5%3E0%2C%20which,positive%20integers%20(excluding%201).

Comment: @Gord452 BP implies this fact, and you can also show this fact implies BP pretty simply in my opinion, so I would say any proof of this fact is roughly equivalent to a proof of BP.

Comment: The special case where $n = 2k$ is equivalent to BP. The general case is strictly stronger—if there were a simple proof using only BP, surely Erdős would have found it.